# Examples of polynomials of single variable $s$ and polynomials in $N$ variables $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n$ with real coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are some examples of polynomials of single variable $s$ and polynomials in $N$ variables $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n$ with real coefficients?

I have concocted the following examples for each. Do these seem right?

Polynomials of a single variable $s$:
\begin{equation}
f(s) = a_0 + a_1s + a_2s^2
\end{equation}

Polynomials in $N$ variables $s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n$ with real coefficients:
\begin{equation}
f(s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n) = a_1s_1 + a_2s_2^2 + a_3 s_3^3 + \cdots + a_n s_n^n
\end{equation}

Comment: You are right - these are polynomials. I assume you user name has a reason? Right in the first lines of wikipedia you find some examples. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial

Comment: Yes, you're right. It does has a reason. I'm currently self-studying functional analysis  and at this point, I think math "hates" me. :) I hope to understand this topic a bit better in the near future.

Comment: Studying functional analysis before knowing what a polynomial is may be the source of your trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are too restrictive for your example of a polynomial with multiple variables. The example you gave is indeed a polynomial but not all have this form.

In fact you can have any product of $s_i$, one part could be for instance $7s_1s{_3}^2{s_4}{s_5}^3$ and a polynomial would be a sum of these terms.

A polynomial of degree $3$ in $x,y$ have up to $10$ coefficients (of course some of them could be zero):
$$P(x)=(a_0)+(a_1x+b_1y)+(a_2x^2+b_2xy+c_2y^2)+(a_3x^3+b_3x^2y+c_3xy^2+d_3y^3)$$

I grouped terms that have the same overall degree:

$$\deg(x^\alpha y^\beta z^\gamma\cdots)=\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\cdots$$

- the general form of a polynomial in $1$ variable is $\displaystyle P(s)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} a_is^i$
- the general form of a polynomial in $m$ variables is $\displaystyle P(s_1,s_2,\cdots,s_m)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\sum\limits_{|\alpha|=i} a(\alpha) {s_1}^{\alpha_1}{s_2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots{s_m}^{\alpha_m}$

with $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_m)\in\mathbb N^m$ and $|\alpha|=\sum\limits_{j=1}^m \alpha_j$

---

A simple example would be for instance the equation of a circle of centre $(a,b)$ and radius $r$.

The equation is $P(x)=0$ where $P$ is a polynomial $P(x,y)=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-r^2$

An hyperbola also has a polynomial equation $0=Q(x,y)=xy-a$